# Java abstract/extends issue

Tags: java, eclipse, oop

I am currently in the process of developing a character generation mechanism for a Java based text game but I've ran into a issue and cannot see where I may have gone wrong. I have a "Character" class, which is abstract and then another class, "NPCharacter" which is meant build on top of this.

```
public abstract class Character {
    public abstract void generateStats();
}

public class NPCharacter extends Character {
    public void generateStats() {

    }
}
```

Eclipse says that "The type NPCharacter cannot subclass the final class Character". Can anyone see the error here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The compiler is confusing your `Character` with `java.lang.Character`. Just use a package and make sure you import *your* `Character`.

```
package com.foo;

public abstract class Character {
    public abstract void generateStats();
}
```

and

```
import com.foo.Character;

public class NPCharacter extends Character {
    public void generateStats() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `Character` is a class in the `java.lang` package, and you can't extended it because it's final. You should rename your `Character` class and/or check your import statements: you have a name collision.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler is saying that you cannot extend the `java.lang.Character` class, which is a `final` class which cannot be subclassed. (The classes in the `java.lang` package are implicitly imported into all Java source files.)

Although the `NPCharacter` class is intending to extend the `Character` abstract class, the compiler can't distinguish between the two.

You'll have to use the fully-qualified class name of the `Character` abstract class, or if that's not possible (due to it not belonging to any package), you won't have any choice other than renaming the `Character` abstract class.

But better yet, **rename your `Character` abstract class to something that doesn't conflict with the name of a class in the `java.lang` package, as that can cause confusion to people reading your code.**

Answer (score 1):

[Character](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) is a standard class in the `java.lang` package, which is auto-imported in every class. Choose another name for your custom class.

Answer (score 0):

Please check you imports. It sounds like the NPCharacter tries to extend another class named Character (perhaps one from the standard library, which can indeed be final).

Preferable refer to your Character class by its full name, i.e. {package name}.Character

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks OK. Are you sure that your NPCharacter class really tries to extend the correct Character class, and not a different one (from a different package) like e.g. java.lang.Character?